# error when converting psd image using imageresizer library

Tags: c#, image-resizing, imageresizer

I am getting following error when converting psd image using imageresizer library(http://imageresizing.net/)

```
"A generic error occurred in GDI+"
```

I am passing following parameters:

```
decoder=freeimage&scale=both&mode=max&quality=100&ignoreicc=false&dpi=96&width=240&height=240
```

I am tring to resize following image:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5s7cXZgfIAoaVB4eGo0T1NOSGM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If FreeImage were decoding the image, you would get a different error, not GDI+.

Please create a [Gist](http://gist.github.com) of your diagnostics page output, and show us that FreeImageDecoder has been correctly installed.